# How to cast datatype in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, types, jupyter-notebook

def clean_data(df):
'''
input: df a dataframe
output: df a dataframe with the all the original columns
'''

```
# START YOUR CODE HERE ---------
df.withColumn('passenger_count', df["passenger_count"].cast("integer"))
df.withColumn('total_amount', df.total_amount.cast('float'))
df.withColumn('tip_amount', df.tip_amount.cast('float'))
df.withColumn('trip_distance', df.trip_distance.cast('float'))
df.withColumn('fare_amount', df.fare_amount.cast('float'))
```

## df.withColumn('tpep_pickup_datetime', to_timestamp(df('tpep_pickup_datetime')))

## df.withColumn('tpep_dropoff_datetime', to_timestamp(df('tpep_dropoff_datetime')))

## df = df.select(df.passenger_count.cast("integer"), df.total_amount.cast('float'), df.tip_amount.cast('float'), df.trip_distance.cast('float'),

## df.fare_amount.cast('float'))

```
# END YOUR CODE HERE -----------
return df
```

why after the above function, the datatype didn't be casted?

Answer (score 0):

df is not mutable, dataframes are immutable.
to do so, you will have to assign new variable.
by default withColumn return new dataframe.

so to apply your changes:

```py
new_df = (df.withColumn('passenger_count', df["passenger_count"].cast("integer"))
.withColumn('total_amount', df.total_amount.cast('float'))
.withColumn('tip_amount', df.tip_amount.cast('float'))
.withColumn('trip_distance', df.trip_distance.cast('float'))
.withColumn('fare_amount', df.fare_amount.cast('float'))
)
```